# How to use windows file paths in Python __doc__

Tags: python, windows, filepath, docstring

I like to give my user's an example in my `__doc__` usage string. Here are the important parts of the code relating to my question.

```
# jmetadata.py
'''
usage:     jmetadata.py inDirPath outFilePath
example:   jmetadata.py "\\\\Hal\\hal free agent 1\\backups\\videos\\" out.txt
'''

<...deleted code...>

def forPyWinTests():
    jmetadata("\\\\Hal\\hal free agent 1\\backups\\videos\\", "out.txt")

NUM_ARGS = 2
def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    print args
    if len(args) != NUM_ARGS or "-h" in args or "--help" in args:
        print __doc__
        sys.exit(2)
    jmetadata(args[0], args[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    # print()
    # forPyWinTests()
```

I EXPECT this behaviour:

```
>jmetadata.py
[]

usage:     jmetadata.py inDirPath outFilePath
example:   jmetadata.py "\\Hal\hal free agent 1\backups\videos\" out.txt


>
```

However, when I copy the example to the command line I EXPECT the program to RUN. Instead I get:

```
>jmetadata.py "\\Hal\hal free agent 1\backups\videos\" out.txt
['\\\\Hal\\hal free agent 1\\backups\\videos" out.txt']

usage:     jmetadata.py inDirPath outFilePath
example:   jmetadata.py "\\Hal\hal free agent 1\backups\videos\" out.txt
```

Note the SECOND LINE in the above. That results from the `print args` command inside `main()`. It is saying that the args list has only 1 element, `['\\\\Hal\\hal free agent 1\\backups\\videos" out.txt']`, instead of 2. This doesn't make sense to me.

I have done a bit more investigation by writing a windows .cmd file. Here is show_args.cmd:

```
rem show_args.cmd
echo %1 
echo %2
```

Here is the result of a run:

```
>show_args.cmd "\\Hal\hal free agent 1\backups\videos\" out.txt

>rem show_args.cmd

>echo "\\Hal\hal free agent 1\backups\videos\"
"\\Hal\hal free agent 1\backups\videos\"

>echo out.txt
out.txt
```

Windows seems to separate the items. I am stumped. Does anyone know what's goin on here?

I hope someone has some insight to share.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try invoking through python: python jmetadata.py "\\Hal\hal free agent 1\backups\videos\" out.txt ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, GodMan. I just did. It causes the same behaviour:                                                   `>python jmetadata.py "\\Hal\hal free agent 1\backups\videos\" out.txt
['\\\\Hal\\hal free agent 1\\backups\\videos" out.txt']

usage:     jmetadata.py inDirPath outFilePath
example:   jmetadata.py "\\Hal\hal free agent 1\backups\videos\" out.txt

>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the trailing backslash. Change this:

```
jmetadata.py "\\Hal\hal free agent 1\backups\videos\" out.txt
```

to this:

```
jmetadata.py "\\Hal\hal free agent 1\backups\videos" out.txt
```

In your test run above, the arguments seen by Python are:

```
['\\\\Hal\\hal free agent 1\\backups\\videos" out.txt']
```

The trailing backspace is being interpreted as an escape character since it is immediately preceding a `"`, which turns your arguments into a single string (or until an unescaped `"` is encountered).

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Thar did the trick. Previously i tried making `__doc__` example:   jmetadata.py "\\\\\Hal\\hal free agent 1\\backups\\videos\\ " out.txt. Which adds a space to the end. This DID NOT work since i am doing os.listdir(args[0]). It yielded: ...     for filename in os.listdir(inDirPath):
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\\\Hal\\hal free agent 1\\backups\\videos\\ /*.*' Thanks for the help. Love and peace, -Joe